# PHP AWS S3 - Download a file using content-disposition without streaming

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, drupal-8

I have some videos on a public S3 bucket and I need to create a download link for them.

Originally, I was going to use Guzzle to get the file from the public link and add the header content-disposition so that the file would be pushed to 
the browser.

```
    $client->get('s3/path');
    $client = $client->withAddedHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' . $videoName);
    return $client;
```

However, I was told by the DevOps team that this would put unnecessary strain on our servers and to find another way.

I know I can se the content-disposition header on the files directly in the bucket, but is there a way of just setting this on access to the public link? If not, is it possible to set a policy on folder in the bucket to always add content-disposition to files that are uploaded in there?

I should also mention that to upload I am using the Drupal 8 module S3FS and a file field meaning that I don't have access to the upload process to set the headers on upload. However, is it possible to update the headers after upload?

Answer (score 1):

> I know I can se the content-disposition header on the files directly
>   in the bucket, but is there a way of just setting this on access to
>   the public link?

Yes, but you will have to create a pre-signed URL and override Content-Disposition header. Here is a modified example from [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-presigned-url.html):

```
//Creating a presigned URL
$cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('GetObject', [
    'Bucket' => 'my-bucket',
    'Key'    => 'testKey',
    'Content-Disposition' => ''
]);

$request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+20 minutes');

// Get the actual presigned-url
$presignedUrl = (string) $request->getUri();
```

Answer (score 0):

[@Sergey Kovalev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1958151/sergey-kovalev)'s answer pointed me in the right direction. You need to use `ResponseContentDisposition` instead of `Content-Disposition`. The AWS docs doesn't specify this for the v3 version of the PHP sdk (...yet).

```
//Creating a presigned URL sdk v3
$cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('GetObject', [
    'Bucket' => 'my-bucket',
    'Key'    => 'testKey',
    'ResponseContentDisposition' => ''
]);

$request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+20 minutes');

// Get the actual presigned-url
$presignedUrl = (string) $request->getUri();
```

```
//Creating a presigned URL sdk v2
$presignedUrl = $s3Client->getObjectUrl(
    'my-bucket',
    'testKey',
    '+20 minutes',
    [
        'ResponseContentDisposition' => ''
    ]
);
```